# Detect whether a pine script/indicator is running in overlay=true mode

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to detect whether a script/indicator is running in overlay=true mode?  I have a pine script that works differently depending on whether it's overlaid on the main panel vs. a separate panel.

At the moment I'm using an input variable to let the user configure which panel it's running in but would rather it was automatic.

Example code:

```
//@version=4
study(title="test", format=format.price, overlay=true)

overlay_main = input(false, title="Overlay on main panel (ie. plot on price rather than on separate indicator panel)")
...
plot(overlay_main ? na : macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd, transp=0)
```

Note, I accept that the user needs to use the "Move To -> New Pane Below" option after they first add the indicator when they want it to run in a separate panel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to detect which pane the indicator is displayed in through pine.